# Can't perform more than one operation on an ImageData object?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to use canvas to mask an image using a few separate masks (I managed to put every one of them in a separate ImageData object).

The mask images are black and white, no alpha channel. I need to layer masks on top of each other, so I need to (un?)premultiply the alpha, or put the red channel in the alpha channel.

It works beautifully when I try to apply only one mask to the original image, but it breaks when I try using more than one. I'm doing it like this:

```
base.iMask = function(cx, imgData, maskLeft, maskRight, maskTop, maskBottom) {
        var index = 0;
        var newdata = cx.createImageData(imgData);

        for (var i=0; i<maskLeft.width; i++) {
            for (var j=0; j<maskLeft.height; j++) {
                index = (i*4)*maskLeft.width+(j*4);

                newdata.data[index+3] = maskLeft.data[index];
            }
        }

        // The same cycle is repeated for each mask (4 total)

        return newdata;
```

The problem is that only the last mask gets applied. I tried to use putImageData and then getImageData before each cycle, but it won't work!

A function that performs a (un)premultiply on an ImageData() object would solve my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, but I'll answer it anyway for the people that might be interested.

The problem was that I was overwriting the pixel data. That's the new code:

```
var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < maskData.width; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < maskData.height; j++) {
        index = (i * 4) * maskData.width + (j * 4);
        maskData.data[index] = 255 - (255 * 4 - stripeTopData.data[index] - stripeBottomData.data[index] - stripeLeftData.data[index] - stripeRightData.data[index]);
    }
}
```

This combines all four masks and generates a B&W image that I can use later to mask my original image.